# how to capture network parameters like RSRP, SINR etc for 5G in android. Will i get both LTE and 5G parameters at the same time in NSA mode?

Tags: android, android-studio, 5g

How dual mode works in android for 5G. How is android APIs are supporting this feature. I am wondering if we will get LTE & 5G network parameters at the same time via different APIs? Please help if anyone has clarity on this.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I doubt there is an API for that

Answer (score 1):

There are different android APIs to get 4G and 5G RF parameters(RSRP,RSRQ and SINR). You can use **CellSignalStrengthLte** to get 4G RF parameters where as use **CellSignalStrengthNr** for 5G.
Here is my implementation of these libraries. You can use the following code to call the nrSignalStrengthInfo function which returns the RF params.

```
 try {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29){
                    val tm: TelephonyManager =
                        context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
                    if (tm.signalStrength != null){
                        Log.i(TAG,"nrSignalStrengthInfo executed")
                        nrSignalStrengthInfo(tm.signalStrength)
                    }
                }
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e(TAG,e.stackTraceToString())               
        }
```

And this is the nrSignalStrengthInfo function which you will be calling.

```
private fun nrSignalStrengthInfo(signalStrength: SignalStrength?){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29){
            if (signalStrength != null) {
                val lteSS = signalStrength.getCellSignalStrengths(CellSignalStrengthLte::class.java)
                val nrSS = signalStrength.getCellSignalStrengths(CellSignalStrengthNr::class.java)
                if (nrSS.isNotEmpty() && lteSS.isNotEmpty()) {
                    this.nrType = "NR_5G_NSA"
                } else if (nrSS.isNotEmpty() && lteSS.isEmpty()) {
                    this.nrType = "NR_5G_SA"
                }else{
                    this.nrType = ""
                    Log.i(TAG,"nrSS not available")
                }
                if (nrSS.isNotEmpty()) {
                    rsrp5g = nrSS[0].ssRsrp.toLong()
                    rsrq5g = nrSS[0].ssRsrq.toLong()
                    sinr5g = nrSS[0].ssSinr.toLong()
                    csiSinr = nrSS[0].csiSinr.toLong()
                }else{
                    if(lteSS.isNotEmpty()){
                        rsrp = lteSS[0].rsrp.toDouble()
                        rsrq = lteSS[0].rsrq.toDouble()

                    }else{
                        rsrp = (-160).toDouble()
                        rsrq = (-30).toDouble()
                    }
                    rsrp5g = -160
                    rsrq5g = -30
                    sinr5g = -30
                    csiSinr = -30
                    pci5g = -1
                    bandsNr = "NA"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!!